# How to show isotope items after filter is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I have some isotope images set up but the problem is when I first load the page all images show (example : all cars and buses are shown), then the default filter kicks in a second later and shows what I want (example: below code would then show cars). It's driving me nuts, does anyone know what I should be doing?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {   

        var $container = $('#portfolio-items');
        var $filter = $('#filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: '.cars',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows',
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear'
            }
        });   


        $filter.find('a').click(function () {
            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $filter.find('a').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
            $container.isotope({
                filter: selector,
                animationOptions: {
                    animationDuration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false,
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

});
```

Comment: How about a jsfiddle? and include your html. We need more info to answer your question.